# Reading a value from Realtime Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, read-write

I have the following json structure:

[image]

Within "all" node I have an attribute "drinkId" and I'm trying to move it outside that child node bringing it one level up.

I'm trying to read the value without any luck

```
const cocktailRef= firebase
      .database()
      .ref("Ratings");  
    cocktailRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {      
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {           
        const drinkIdPass = child.ref.child("all").child("drinkId").value(); 

        child.ref.update({ drinkId: drinkIdPass }); 
     })
  })
```

I've tried different variants of ".value()", same problem

Comment: Change `child.ref.child("all")...` to `child("all").child("drinkId").value`... e.g. child is the child node and child.ref is a path to child contained in the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any `value()` method on a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val). It's `val()` Try refactoring your code like this:

```js
const cocktailRef= firebase.database().ref("Ratings");  

cocktailRef.once("value").then(async (snapshot) => {  
  const updates = { }    
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {           
    const drinkIdPass = child.val().all.drinkId
    updates[`${child.key}/drinkId`] = drinkIdPass 
  })

  await cocktailRef.update(updates)
  console.log("Data updated")
})
```

Comment: Depending on the data under `/all`, `child.child('all/drinkId').val()` might be the better choice.